# Transferred Hosts and setting cookies doesn't work now

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working on a project and everything was working on the temporary test site. Today, I migrated everything over to a new host (justhost.com) and for some reason, when calling the `setcookie` function in PHP, no cookies are set. I checked multiple browsers and nothing works.

Here is an example of the setcookie function I am using:

```
setcookie("blah", $login_email, $time, $path);
```

The `$path` is just `"/"`  if that is relevant. The code is completely unchanged from when I transferred it, aside from the database details. I can't understand why cookies are not being set, however.

Are there any settings in a host I may need to change? I'm coming up short.

**UPDATE:** I was able to set cookies by echoing some jQuery. But I'd still like to know why the PHP method doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem. I had the code in my body tag because part of it was also outputting some information. I changed it so that I can move the `setcookie` function above the html tag. The problem was that some hosts send headers first and then do not send headers once other data (like the body) begins to load. I also ran into a similar problem later, this time caused by whitespace. I had a comment at the top of the php script preceding the `<?php` and deleting this remedied another issue. One final issue in an included file of functions needed to be dealt with using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()`.

Comment: What is the `$time` value used ?

Comment: do you have any log? have you tried to dump any variable in the process to get partial results and discover problems?

Comment: I was going to ask whether the domain had changed as well as your host, but from your example it doesn't look like you set it so I assume it will inherit whatever is detected.

Comment: `$time` is the current time + 30 days. It worked on the previous domain. I've dumped all variables involved and they all work. Which is to be expected, since they worked before. The domain was in fact changed. I deleted all cookies of the previous domain and tried different web browsers and different devices.